# Rating parameters JSON input from android device to WordPress site?

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress

**My problem statement:**
I want to know that what would be the JSON input for rating parameters while submitting the form through android device?

What I've tried:

```
POST URL: http://testwordpresssite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments
JSON Input:
{
    "post": "1555",
    "content": "this is test comment from JSON",
    "author_name": "this is test",
    "author_email": "amitgupta2388@gmail.com",
    "overall":"4",
    "quality":"3",
    "support":"2",
    "price":"1",
    "products":"5"
}
```

My rating parameters are *overall, quality, support, price and products*.
Content is getting stored in database but not rating params.
I'm using **globo 1.1.7** WordPress theme.

**Additional Info:**
We've two tables where post review and star rating stored ***wp_comments*** and ***wp_commentmeta*** respectively.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to send numbers instead of strings - e.g. `"overall":4, "quality": 3, ...` ?

Comment: JSON input should be in key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional information then you have to add a comment_meta in wp_commentmeta table 
Like:

```
<?php add_comment_meta( $comment_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ); ?>
```

Link:  [comment-meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta)

Comment: Thank you for replying but when I submit the rating & review using Website it works fine and store the information in both the tables. But when I try to submit the inputs through android device using REST call, it didn't save the ratings. I don't know whether I'm using correct JSON input or not. Please advice.